# python-pandas and databases like mysql

Tags: python, pandas

The documentation for Pandas has numerous examples of best practices for working with data stored in various formats.

However, I am unable to find any good examples for working with databases like MySQL for example.

Can anyone point me to links or give some code snippets of how to convert query results using **mysql-python** to data frames in Pandas efficiently ?

Comment: Documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231646/using-pandas-io-sql-read-frame-can-i-parse-dates-as-in-read-csv

Comment: Also take a look at [Blaze](http://blaze.pydata.org/docs/latest/index.html).

Comment: If you're willing to spend money, I believe that Wes McKinney's book ("Python for Data Analysis") has some useful examples.

Answer (score 103):

As Wes says, io/sql's read_sql will do it, once you've gotten a database connection using a DBI compatible library.  We can look at two short examples using the `MySQLdb` and `cx_Oracle` libraries to connect to Oracle and MySQL and query their data dictionaries. Here is the example for `cx_Oracle`:

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle

ora_conn = cx_Oracle.connect('your_connection_string')
df_ora = pd.read_sql('select * from user_objects', con=ora_conn)    
print 'loaded dataframe from Oracle. # Records: ', len(df_ora)
ora_conn.close()
```

And here is the equivalent example for `MySQLdb`:

```
import MySQLdb
mysql_cn= MySQLdb.connect(host='myhost', 
                port=3306,user='myusername', passwd='mypassword', 
                db='information_schema')
df_mysql = pd.read_sql('select * from VIEWS;', con=mysql_cn)    
print 'loaded dataframe from MySQL. records:', len(df_mysql)
mysql_cn.close()
```

Answer (score 58):

For recent readers of this question: pandas have the following warning in their [docs for version 14.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html):

> Warning: Some of the existing functions or function aliases have been
>   deprecated and will be removed in future versions. This includes:
>   tquery, uquery, read_frame, frame_query, write_frame.

And:

> Warning: The support for the ‘mysql’ flavor when using DBAPI connection objects has
>   been deprecated. MySQL will be further supported with SQLAlchemy
>   engines (GH6900).

This makes many of the answers here outdated. You should use `sqlalchemy`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
engine = create_engine('dialect://user:pass@host:port/schema', echo=False)
f = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM mytable', engine, index_col = 'ID')
```

Comment: loading a table with 133 rows and 7 columns takes around 30 secs.. can you give some insights regarding why is that?

Comment: @idoda [in general this is not the question's topic and it's better to ask a new question so you'd get more opinions]. Are you sure this is not a matter of request delay? Is simply sending the query and retrieving the results significantly faster?

Comment: @Korem I did thought about opening a new one, but I wanted to make sure it is not a trivial one first. When I use an mySql client (Sequel pro) and query the database, reuslts come up much faster. When you say "simply sending and then retrieving", is that what you mean? (using a client)

Comment: @idoda I mean comparing the time it takes to execute `engine.execute("select * FROM mytable")` with the time it takes to execute `pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM mytable', engine)`

Comment: Can one pass a sqlalchemy query (session.query as in my answer below) directly to a pandas method? That would be a ripper!

Answer (score 23):

For the record, here is an example using a sqlite database:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect("whatever.sqlite") as con:
    sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name"
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con)
    print df.shape
```

Comment: You can specify the column to use as an index by specifying `index_col='timestamp'` in `frame_query`.

Answer (score 21):

I prefer to create queries with [**SQLAlchemy**](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/), and then make a DataFrame from it. **SQLAlchemy** makes it easier to combine **SQL** conditions Pythonically if you intend to mix and match things over and over.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from pandas import DataFrame
import datetime

# We are connecting to an existing service
engine = create_engine('dialect://user:pwd@host:port/db', echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base()

# And we want to query an existing table
tablename = Table('tablename', 
    Base.metadata, 
    autoload=True, 
    autoload_with=engine, 
    schema='ownername')

# These are the "Where" parameters, but I could as easily 
# create joins and limit results
us = tablename.c.country_code.in_(['US','MX'])
dc = tablename.c.locn_name.like('%DC%')
dt = tablename.c.arr_date >= datetime.date.today() # Give me convenience or...

q = session.query(tablename).\
            filter(us & dc & dt) # That's where the magic happens!!!

def querydb(query):
    """
    Function to execute query and return DataFrame.
    """
    df = DataFrame(query.all());
    df.columns = [x['name'] for x in query.column_descriptions]
    return df

querydb(q)
```

Comment: Also you must specify the driver if it's not the same as [the SQLAlchemy's default one](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html): `dialect+driver://user:pwd@host:port/db`

Answer (score 11):

MySQL example:

```
import MySQLdb as db
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas.io.sql import frame_query

database = db.connect('localhost','username','password','database')
data     = frame_query("SELECT * FROM data", database)
```

Comment: `frame_query` is now deprecated. Now use `pd.read_sql(query, db)` instead.

Answer (score 8):

The same syntax works for Ms SQL server using podbc also.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas.io.sql as psql

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=servername;DATABASE=mydb;UID=username;PWD=password') 
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sql = ("""select * from mytable""")

df = psql.frame_query(sql, cnxn)
cnxn.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

And this is how you connect to PostgreSQL using psycopg2 driver (install with "apt-get install python-psycopg2" if you're on Debian Linux derivative OS).

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='datawarehouse' user='user1' host='localhost' password='uberdba'")

q = """select month_idx, sum(payment) from bi_some_table"""

df3 = psql.frame_query(q, conn)
```

Answer (score 4):

For Sybase the following works (with http://python-sybase.sourceforge.net)

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import Sybase

df = psql.frame_query("<Query>", con=Sybase.connect("<dsn>", "<user>", "<pwd>"))
```

Answer (score 4):

`pandas.io.sql.frame_query` is deprecated. Use `pandas.read_sql` instead.

Answer (score 1):

### import the module

```
import pandas as pd
import oursql
```

### connect

```
conn=oursql.connect(host="localhost",user="me",passwd="mypassword",db="classicmodels")
sql="Select customerName, city,country from customers order by customerName,country,city"
df_mysql = pd.read_sql(sql,conn)
print df_mysql
```

That works just fine and using pandas.io.sql frame_works (with the deprecation warning). Database used is the sample database from mysql tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine.

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import pandas as pd
con = mdb.connect(‘127.0.0.1’, ‘root’, ‘password’, ‘database_name’);
with con:
 cur = con.cursor()
 cur.execute(“select random_number_one, random_number_two, random_number_three from randomness.a_random_table”)
 rows = cur.fetchall()
 df = pd.DataFrame( [[ij for ij in i] for i in rows] )
 df.rename(columns={0: ‘Random Number One’, 1: ‘Random Number Two’, 2: ‘Random Number Three’}, inplace=True);
 print(df.head(20))
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped for me for connecting to **AWS MYSQL(RDS)** from **python 3.x** based ***lambda function*** and loading into a pandas DataFrame

```
import json
import boto3
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
user = 'username'
password = 'XXXXXXX'
client = boto3.client('rds')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='xxx.xxxxus-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com', port=3306, user=user, passwd=password, db='database name', connect_timeout=5)
    df= pd.read_sql('select * from TableName limit 10',con=conn)
    print(df)
    # TODO implement
    #return {
    #    'statusCode': 200,
    #    'df': df
    #}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Postgres users

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd

conn = psycopg2.connect("database='datawarehouse' user='user1' host='localhost' password='uberdba'")

customers = 'select * from customers'

customers_df = pd.read_sql(customers,conn)

customers_df
```

Comment: Could you point out the difference to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18752373/5350038) of @Will and why your solution should be chosen?

Answer (score 0):

Using **mysql.connector**, you could write something like this:

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

# Database credentials
DB_HOST = 'host_ip'
DB_NAME = 'db_name or schema'
DB_USER = 'user_name'
DB_PASS = 'password'

try:
    # Connect to the database
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=DB_HOST,
        database=DB_NAME,
        user=DB_USER,
        password=DB_PASS
    )

    # Create a cursor object to execute SQL queries
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Example query
    query = "SELECT * FROM your_table"

    # Execute the query
    cursor.execute(query)

    # Fetch all the rows
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    # Get column names
    column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]

    # Create a DataFrame from the fetched rows and column names
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=column_names)

    # Process or analyze the DataFrame as needed
    print(df)

    # Close the cursor and connection
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print(f"Failed to connect to MySQL: {error}")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).