# itter from some odbc connection to pandas table with out a csv

Tags: pandas, pyodbc

I have some base info in a pandas DataFrame.  I need to join it with some reference tables that I have access via a pyodbc connection.  Is there any way to get the sql result set into a pandas DataFrame without writing the result set out to a csv first?

It just seems like a waste to have this extra step out to csv and into a DataFrame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've gotten `pyodbc` to work with my `SQL Server` instance, then, with some help from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065051/python-pandas-and-databases-like-mysql), I got the sql return to load a dataframe.

I already setup a `pyodbc` connection, then made a call to it.

```
import pyodbc

import pandas.io.sql as psql

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(your_connection_info) 
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sql = ("""SELECT * FROM Source""")

df = psql.frame_query(sql, cnxn)
cnxn.close()
```

`df` should return your dataframe now.  The hardest part for me was getting `pyodbc` up and running - I had to use `freetds` and it took a lot of trial and error to get it work.

Comment: perfect works. saves a step...  Now if only there was a way to do it from a pyTable.root.table.where('field == value') then I could avoid all intermediate csv files.