# Using pandas.io.sql.read_frame, can I parse_dates, as in read_csv?

Tags: python, sql, datetime, pandas

I am reading a `data_frame` directly from a database using `pandas.io.sql.read_frame`:

```
cnx = pandas.io.sql.connect(host='srv',user='me',password='pw',database='db')
df = pandas.io.sql.read_frame('sql_query',cnx)
```

It works nicely in retrieving the data. But I would like to parse one of the columns as a `datetime64`, akin to what can be done when reading from a CSV file, e.g.:

```
df2 = pandas.io.read_csv(csv_file, parse_dates=[0])
```

But there is no `parse_dates` flag for `read_frame`. What alternative approach is recommended?

The same question applies to the `index_col` in read_csv, which indicates which col. should be the index. Is there a recommended way to do this with read_frame?

Comment: I contributed the latest version of ``pandas.io.sql`` to pandas, and it is still a work in progress, particularly detection of specific datatypes. I expect an upcoming version will contain big improvements. You can catch up on some recent discussion here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1662 and here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2717

Comment: That said, for me, MySQL TIMESTAMP columns are parsed correctly as ``pd.tslib.Timestamp`` objects. And there is an ``index_col`` argument for ``read_frame``. Are you using the latest stable release of pandas?

Comment: @DanAllan Good work on pandas.io.sql! I am using pandas v. '0.10.1'
I was trying to use `index_col=[0]`, as I do with `pandas.io.read_csv`, and it failed: **KeyError: u'no item named 0'**. After reading your comment, I tried `index_col=[key_name_string]` instead, and it worked. Also, as the required column index is a datetime, pandas now correctly identifies the DataFrame as having a DatetimeIndex. So my problem is solved, thank you! However, before I set the col. as index, the DateTime type was not parsed correctly, so a `parse_dates` argument for `pandas.io.sql.read_frame` would be great.

Comment: I added this to our discussion. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: This is also relevant for reading from SQLite dbs, since SQLite has no datetime column affinity (you just store timestamps as ISO 8601 text).

Answer (score 2):

This question is very old by now. pandas 0.10 is very old as well.
In the newest version of pandas 0.16, the read_frame method has been depricated in favour of the read_sql.
Even so, the documentation says that just like the read_csv function, it takes a parse_dates argument [Pandas 0.16 read_frame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.sql.read_frame.html)

It seems the parse_dates argument appeared in 0.14, at the same time as read_frame was depricated.
The read_sql function seems to be a rename of the read_frame, so just updating your pandas version to 0.14 or higher and renaming your function will give you access to this argument.
Here is the doc for the read_sql function: [Pandas 0.16 read_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.sql.read_sql.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
data_frame["column"] = pandas.to_datetime(data_frame["column"])
```

should work by default but if not you can specify options. See the [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.tseries.tools.to_datetime.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pandas.io.sql.read_frame('sql_query', index=['date_column_name'], con=cnx)
```

where `date_column_name` is the name of the column in the database that contains date elements. `sql_query` should then be of the form `select date_column_name, data_column_name from ...`

Pandas (as of 0.13+) will then automatically parse it to a date format if it resembles a date string.

```
In [34]: df.index
Out[34]: 
    <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
```