# Python class to convert all tables in a database to pandas dataframes

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I'm trying to achieve the following. I want to create a python Class that transforms all tables in a database to pandas dataframes.

This is how I do it, which is not very generic...

```
class sql2df():
    def __init__(self, db, password='123',host='127.0.0.1',user='root'):
        self.db = db

        mysql_cn= MySQLdb.connect(host=host,
                        port=3306,user=user, passwd=password, 
                        db=self.db)

        self.table1 = psql.frame_query('select * from table1', mysql_cn)
        self.table2 = psql.frame_query('select * from table2', mysql_cn)
        self.table3 = psql.frame_query('select * from table3', mysql_cn)
```

Now I can access all tables like so:

```
my_db = sql2df('mydb')
my_db.table1
```

I want something like:

```
class sql2df():
    def __init__(self, db, password='123',host='127.0.0.1',user='root'):
        self.db = db

        mysql_cn= MySQLdb.connect(host=host,
                        port=3306,user=user, passwd=password, 
                        db=self.db)
        tables = (""" SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '%s' """ % self.db)
        <some kind of iteration that gives back all the tables in df as class attributes>
```

Suggestions are most welcome...

Answer (score 5):

I would use SQLAlchemy for this:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:123@127.0.0.1/%s" % db)
```

Note the [syntax](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#database-urls) is dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database.

```
def db_to_frames_dict(engine):
    meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
    meta.reflect(bind=engine)
    tables = meta.sorted_tables
    return {t: pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM %s' % t.name,
                           engine.raw_connection())
                   for t in tables}
    # Note: frame_query is depreciated in favor of read_sql
```

*This returns a dictionary, but you could equally well have these as class attributes (e.g. by updating the class dict and `__getitem__`)*

```
class SQLAsDataFrames:
    def __init__(self, engine):
        self.__dict__ = db_to_frames_dict(engine)  # allows .table_name access
    def __getitem__(self, key):                    # allows [table_name] access
        return self.__dict__[key]
```

*In pandas 0.14 the sql code has been rewritten to take engines, and IIRC there is helpers for all tables and for reading all of a table (using `read_sql(table_name)`).*

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about sqlalchemy! The problem I'm having still is how to 'dynamically' set a class attributes, eg what you refer to as 'updating the class dict'.

Comment: @bowlby for attributes: `class A: def __init__(self, d): self.__dict__.update(d)` where d is the dict above. Maybe `def __getitem__(self, key): return self.__dict__[key]` for good measure.

Comment: +Andy Hayden think you are missing the closing ) on the select

Comment: How do I call sql2df? what is the expected argument? eg sql2df(?) and then how to access the tables?

Comment: if i try t=[]
sql2df(t) I get global name 'sqlalchmey' is not defined

Comment: @dartdog shows how completely untested this answer is! The expected output of sql2df is a dict of dataframes... should choose a better name!

Comment: closer?? dunno about the reflect, my 1st attempt at getting sqlalchemy hooked up :-) but when I do "db_to_frames_dict(engine)" I get global name 'psql' is not defined
(I'm using mysql (mariadb if that makes a diff..)

Comment: @dartdog my guess is OP had imported it as `from pandas.io import sql as psql`... no need as it's available at top level!

Comment: nope ----> 5     return {t: sql.read_sql('SELECT * FROM %s' % t, engine.connect())}
      6     # Note: frame_query is depreciated in favor of read_sql

NameError: global name 'sql' is not defined  Tried pd.sql as well...

Comment: @dartdog try top level pd.read_sql (I updated post!) Dang, I really should test this properly!

Comment: think it may need the reflect? from my dim slow reading (remember this is my 1st go with sqlalchemy!) currently when I do with the updated code >>> frames=db_to_frames_dict(engine)
frames I get {} (fwiw I am getting table results out of my connection so I have the base system working)

Comment: Maybe the syntax is this: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/reflection.html#reflecting-all-tables-at-once (I vaguely recall from my attempt at pandas sql with SQLA, strange that it needs it but I think it does...) Thanks for testing/putting up with this! Updated post...

Comment: I'm adding what I have in a new answer it is erroring though You have a few edit issues MetaData and reflect...

Comment: Meta needs to be MetaData I think? see my new post which I think is upto date with yours

Comment: @dartdog goodness so many errors, I think the last is to use raw_connection... I'm hoping you can get away without closing here :s http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401392/read-frame-with-sqlalchemy-mysql-and-pandas

Comment: Ok this db_to_frames_dict works but.. but SQLAsDataFrames not working class creation. I'm not exactly sure what the result of the db_to_frames is it seems to be a collection of all my data so I have not worked out how to address the resulting data yet?

Comment: @dartdog it **should** be a dictionary of table names to DataFrames (for each table in the db). I have a feeling bug is should be using table name as key (i.e. should be `{t.name: ..}` rather that a Table object)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have now:
Imports

```
 import sqlalchemy
 from sqlalchemy import create_engine
 from sqlalchemy import Table, Column,Date, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey
 from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
 from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
 import pandas as pd

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:password@127.0.0.1/%s" % 'surveytest')
def db_to_frames_dict(engine):
    meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
    meta.reflect(bind=engine)
    tables = meta.sorted_tables
    return {t: pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM %s' % t.name, engine.connect())
               for t in tables}
# Note: frame_query is depreciated in favor of read_sql
```

Have not started to fiddle with this part yet! below:

```
class SQLAsDataFrames:
    def __init__(self, engine):
        self.__dict__ = db_to_frames_dict(engine)  # allows .table_name access
    def __getitem__(self, key):                    # allows [table_name] access
        return self.__dict__[key]
```

And the error: Which looks like at least it is trying to get the table names...

```
frames=db_to_frames_dict(engine)
frames

Error on sql SELECT * FROM tbl_original_survey_master
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-4-6b0006e1ce47> in <module>()
 ----> 1 frames=db_to_frames_dict(engine)
 >>>> more tracebck
 ---> 53             con.rollback()
 54         except Exception:  # pragma: no cover
 55             pass

 AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'rollback'
```

Thank you for sticking with this!

Comment: as above, Connection object is apparently not a connection! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401392/read-frame-with-sqlalchemy-mysql-and-pandas Apologies again for poor initial state of answer!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help, this is what I ended up using:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column,Date, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
import pandas as pd

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:123@127.0.0.1/%s" % 'mydb')

def db_to_frames_dict(engine):
    meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
    meta.reflect(engine)
    tables = meta.tables.keys()
    cnx = engine.raw_connection()

    return {t: pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM %s' % t, cnx )
               for t in tables}

class SQLAsDataFrames:
    def __init__(self, engine):
        self.__dict__ = db_to_frames_dict(engine)  # allows .table_name access
    def __getitem__(self, key):                    # allows [table_name] access
        return self.__dict__[key]
```