# Load a dataframe to SQL Server from pandas?

Tags: sql-server, pandas, pyodbc, pandas-to-sql

I am trying to test a script that will push a dataframe to SQL Server.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

conn_str = (
    r'Driver={SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=wouldntuliketoknow\SQLEXPRESS;'
    r'Database=test;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

globalID = [9581091, 9581091, 79735371, 79735371, 79735371]
ID = [53506312, 961273620, 53506312, 79735371, 135962137]
names = ['meh',
        'cool',
        'dude whatever',
        'foo',
        'bar']

df = pd.DataFrame({'globalID': globalID, 'ID': ID, 'name': names})
df.to_sql("pandas", cnxn)
print(conn_str)
```

It is throwing an error:

> pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")

What am I doing wrong?

I'm not sure where the sqllite_master is coming from in the error?

Is the cursor necessary?

Comment: "SQLite is the only supported option if SQLAlchemy is not installed." per http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: Well I have SQLAlchemy install, what do I need to add to my script?

Comment: You need to supply a SQLAlchemy engine to `to_sql`...

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661754/get-data-from-pandas-into-a-sql-server-with-pyodbc