# How can I create a loop with pandas read_csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I create a loop with pandas read_csv?

I need to create a data loop to list and save to the database.

How can I do this loop with the data from a csv?

thank you all for your attention

```
produtos = pd.read_csv('tabela.csv', delimiter=';')
        for produto in produtos:
            print(produto['NOME'])
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question and add desired outcome? Or perhaps pseudocode

Comment: I have a CSV with data, I need to save this data in a database. There are several rows with data and headed by names of possible columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have files that you need to save, I recommend this

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)
path = "C:/path/to/directory"

# list all files in the directory, assuming this directory 
# contains only files csv files that you need to save 
for file in os.listdir(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(path+file)
    # some other data cleaning/manipulation

    # write dataframe to database
    df.to_sql("table_name", con=engine)
```

Alternative, you can create a list with all files locations and iterate through that one instead. More info on [to_sql()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) and check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661754/get-data-from-pandas-into-a-sql-server-with-pyodbc)

Answer (score 8):

To iterate in the DataFrame resulted by calling pandas `read_csv` you should use the command `iterrows()` for iteration, as in the below example:

```
for produto in produtos.iterrows():
    print(produto['NOME'])
```

Comment: this doesnt iterate through pandas.read_csv. It iterates through pandas.DataFrame. read_csv simply reads the files and puts it into a DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

If you can create loop with Pandas by column name:

```
produtos = pd.read_csv('tabela.csv', delimiter=';')
for i, produto in produtos.iterrows():
    print(produto['NOME'])
```

But if you want to insert directly on your database use sqlalchemy and function to_sql like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
...
engine = create_engine("mysql://user:pwd@localhost/database")
produtos = pd.read_csv('tabela.csv', delimiter=';')
if_exists_do = 'append'
produtos.to_sql('table_name', con=engine, if_exists=if_exists_do)
```

Then it will be inserted on database. The var 'if_exists_do' can receive value 'replace' if you want this.