# Pandas .to_sql function throws ImportError (DLL Load Failed)

Tags: python, pandas

When I'm calling `.to_sql()` on a Pandas series, I get an `ImportError` exception:

> Exception has occurred: ImportError
>   DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I imported `pandas` and `pyodbc`, and I am able to connect to the DB server and read data through `.read_sql_query()` as well as use pandas Dataframes elsewhere in the code. It only shows up when I try to call `.to_sql()`

Pandas version 0.23.4

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=' + prm.DATASOURCE + ';DATABASE=' + prm.DATABASE + ';UID=' + prm.USER + ';PWD=' + prm.PASSWORD)
df.to_sql('table_name', conn, if_exists='append', index=True, index_label=['country_id','year_id'])
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you mean to have your second argument to df.to_sql be "self.conn" instead of "conn"?

Comment: @pistolpete yes, thank you for noticing

Comment: @Teddy, I don't think so. OP said they could use pd.read_sql_query()

Comment: @pistolpete, thank you for pointing this out. I think @Nuno should explore this route first as a simple googling of `ImportError (DLL Load Failed)` show a lot of SO posts with similar issues marked as solved. :)

Comment: @Teddy, no pandas.DataFrame.to_sql wants a sqlalchemy engine, not a pyodbc connection. See my post below.

Comment: Yep, just saw that. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get data from pandas into a SQL server with PYODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661754/get-data-from-pandas-into-a-sql-server-with-pyodbc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661754/get-data-from-pandas-into-a-sql-server-with-pyodbc) and the [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-sql) it seems like the problem is that DataFrame.to_sql is meant to be used with SQLAlchemy. Do you have SQLAlchemy installed? If so, maybe try passing in a SQLAlchemy engine instead of your pyodbc connection.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Create your engine.
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://user:password@server/database')

# Use the engine instead of the pyodbc connection
df.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='append', index=True, index_label=['country_id','year_id'])
```

From the Pandas docs linked above:

> The pandas.io.sql module provides a collection of query wrappers to both facilitate data retrieval and to reduce dependency on DB-specific API......
>   If SQLAlchemy is not installed, a fallback is only provided for sqlite.

From the [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql)

> con : sqlalchemy.engine.Engine or sqlite3.Connection
>
> Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that
>   library. 
>       Legacy support is provided for sqlite3.Connection objects.

Comment: Changed to sqlalchemy by .create_engine and that solved the problem! Didn't know you could read but not write with pyodbc directly. Thank you

Comment: I didn't know that either until I looked into it, and honestly it's not intuitive at all. I wish they made it more explicit by renaming the "con" parameter to "engine". You're welcome.