# Trying to insert pandas dataframe to temporary table

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, pyodbc, temp-tables

I'm looking to create a temp table and insert a some data into it. I have used pyodbc extensively to pull data but I am not familiar with writing data to SQL from a python environment. I am doing this at work so I dont have the ability to create tables, but I can create temp and global temp tables. My intent is to insert a relatively small dataframe (150rows x 4cols)into a temp table and reference it throughout my session, my program structure makes it so that a global variable in the session will not suffice.I am getting the following error when trying the piece below, what am I doing wrong?

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc


conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=SERVER;'
                      'Database=DATABASE;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

temp_creator = '''CREATE TABLE #rankings (Col1 int, Col2 int)'''

cursor.execute(temp_creator)

df_insert = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : [1, 2, 3], 'Col2':[4,5,6]})
df_insert.to_sql(r'#rankings', conn, if_exists='append')
read_query = '''SELECT * FROM #rankings'''
df_back = pd.read_sql(read_query,conn)
```

Comment: Is it on Windows?

Comment: Yeah this is windows OS

Comment: I would try DSN connection. It's probably the easiest way. Other methods might need some time to try it out. Check the documentation for instruction. https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows

Comment: Im not really worried about the connection that is fine, I've tested this code and the only line that fails is the df_insert.to_sql(r'#rankings', conn, if_exists='append'), I can create the temp table and read from it but I'm having trouble inserting my dataframe

Comment: Sorry, for inserting need to use ```sqlalchemy```. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661754/get-data-from-pandas-into-a-sql-server-with-pyodbc

Answer (score 11):

Pandas.to_sql is failing there.  But for SQL Server 2016+/Azure SQL Database there's a better way in any case.  Instead of having pandas insert each row, send the whole dataframe to the server in JSON format and insert it in a single statement.  Like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Sql Server};'
                      'Server=localhost;'
                      'Database=tempdb;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

temp_creator = '''CREATE TABLE #rankings (Col1 int, Col2 int);'''
cursor.execute(temp_creator)

df_insert = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : [1, 2, 3], 'Col2':[4,5,6]})

df_json = df_insert.to_json(orient='records')
print(df_json)

load_df = """\
insert into #rankings(Col1, Col2)
select Col1, Col2
from openjson(?)
with 
(
  Col1 int '$.Col1',
  Col2 int '$.Col2'
);
"""

cursor.execute(load_df,df_json)

#df_insert.to_sql(r'#rankings', conn, if_exists='append')
read_query = '''SELECT * FROM #rankings'''
df_back = pd.read_sql(read_query,conn)
print(df_back)
```

which outputs

```
[{"Col1":1,"Col2":4},{"Col1":2,"Col2":5},{"Col1":3,"Col2":6}]
   Col1  Col2
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: What about Oracle?  Is this also the best way?

Comment: You should ask that in a separate question with the [oracle] tag, which is watched by people who might know the answer.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft could you explain the `WITH (...)` statement when loading the json?

Comment: The `with` clause in OPENJSON specifies the projection of JSON values into relational columns with SQL Server data types.  It's documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: To use this JSON "trick" with `to_sql()`, check out the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/1fb0f1c3f5edbf6192e596de8350f205).

Comment: What do the $ signs mean in '$.Col1' and '$.Col2'

Comment: $ refers to the current JSON node.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting into temp table using **sqlalchemy** works great:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mssql://sql-server/MY_DB?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
df1.to_sql(name='#my_temp_table', con=engine)
df2 = pd.read_sql_query(sql='select * from #my_temp_table', con=engine)
# Now we can test they are the same:
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1,df2.drop(columns=['index']))
```