# SQLAlchemy insert and update rows based on dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

**PROBLEM**

I have the following dataframe (I am working with confidential data, so I will provide a sample):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df

    name    weight  height  smoke_or_not
0   Ajitesh 84       183          no
1   Shail   79       186          yes
2   Seema   67       158          no
3   Nidhi   52       155          no
```

I am saving this dataframe as a sql table using the following code. It is not included here, but I have already made de connection to the SQL Server database.

```
df.to_sql('table name', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

This dataframe is coming from a file that is beging updated daily. This update may contain new rows or even modifications of the existing rows.

For example, here I have modifications in the first row and a new row:

```
    name    weight  height  smoke_or_not
0   John    84       183          yes
1   Shail   79       186          yes
2   Seema   67       158          no
3   Nidhi   52       155          no
4   Mary    70       162          no
```

**QUESTION**

How could I identify the changes in existing rows and the new rows to run INSERT and UPDATE queries on SQLAlchemy?

I have my `df` coming from the file that is being updated daily.

I also have a `df2` that is coming from the SQL database with a SELECT * from table query.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

I have tried using:

```
changes = pd.merge(df, df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
right_only = changes[changes['_merge'] == 'right_only']
right_only

    name    weight  height  smoke_or_not    _merge
4   John    84        183     yes           right_only
5   Mary    70        162     no            right_only
```

With this I can get a new dataframe with all the rows that were changed + the new row. However, there are no distinction about which rows were changed and which ones are the new ones. So I can't separate which rows I am going to UPDATE or INSERT. Is there any easier way to do that?

Comment: You probably don't want to do this comparison on the client side, think if you have billions of rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the pandas data frame into a temporary table or staging table, and then upsert the data in TSQL using [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or UPDATE and INSERT.

One simply way to get the pandas dataframe into SQL where you can reference the data in a SQL query is to send it as JSON and parse it on the server. See eg: [Trying to insert pandas dataframe to temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615642/trying-to-insert-pandas-dataframe-to-temporary-table/57616645#57616645)