# Facing issue while loading table as Pyspark DataFrame from sql

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

i am trying to transfer a table from Postgres to Sql Server. My database is located in remote server. So i have used the following approach

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

appName = "PySpark PostgreSQL Example - via psycopg2"
master = "11.220.202.11"

spark = SparkSession.builder.master(master).appName(appName).getOrCreate()

engine = create_engine(
    "postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@11.220.202.11/testdb?client_encoding=utf8")
pdf = pd.read_sql('select * from test_table', engine)

# Convert Pandas dataframe to spark DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
```

after this step i was planning to dump the data in Sql Server.

But the problem i am facing probably memory issue, as my system hangs and it has shutdown twice, i have **8 GB RAM** and the table size is around **3 GB**. Is there a way to directly load the data into sql server instead of loading it to pyspark dataframe. Please do suggest improvements and  alternatives.

TIA

Comment: you can use the pandas dataframe `to_sql()` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661754/get-data-from-pandas-into-a-sql-server-with-pyodbc)

Comment: Avoid loading data directly in pandas data frame instead load in pyspark data frame using PostgreSQL JDBC Driver depending source data volume and available memory implement batching